# ES6 | Change data of Class A in Class B?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-class

My problem is that I've already a huge file of code so I try to seperate parts of it in different files/classes for a better overview. All of the new seperated classes have to get or set data from the Main Class called Person (in this exmaple) so how I can manage that ?

Here is a small example of my problem.

```
class Person {
    constructor(name, age) {
        this._name = name
        this._age = age
    }

    entryPoint() {
        ClassTwo.someEditFunction()
    }
}

class ClassTwo {
    static someEditFunction() {
        // here I wanna edit this._name from Class Person (without returing(?))
    }
}

let person1 = new Person('John', 15)
person1.entryPoint()
```

Comment: what stops you from redefining the entire constructor function or values from `person1`? Apart from it looking like bad style...

Comment: Why do you want to use `this._name` instead of `ClassTwo.someEditFunction(this)` and `static someEditFunction(obj) { obj._name }`?

Comment: Why is `ClassTwo` a `class` with a single static method? You really should not have such things. Just use a normal `function` declaration and pass the instance as an argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is really a good way to structure your code, but you can `bind()` the `ClassTwo` function to the instance of `Person` to get what you want.

```js
class ClassTwo {
  static someEditFunction() {
    // here I wanna edit this._name from Class Person (without returing(?))
    this._name = "changed"
  }
}

class Person {
  constructor(name, age) {
    this._name = name
    this._age = age
  }

  entryPoint() {
    // ClassTwo.someEditFunction.bind(this)()
    // call() is a better fit
    ClassTwo.someEditFunction.call(this)

  }
}



let person1 = new Person('John', 15)
person1.entryPoint()
console.log(person1)
```

Comment: `call` instead of `bind` would look more natural imho, not important though.

Comment: Thank you, that was what I looking for! Do u know how call a function from ClassTwo inside of ClassTwo?

Comment: Thanks @ASDFGerte - you're of course correct. I'll add an edit.

Comment: @bonblow - it depends on what you mean. To call a static function you can just call like you did before: `ClassTwo.anotherFunction()`. If you're calling a method from an instance, you can use `this`